VBA Submodule not running multiple for loops
I have VBA code here that essentially pulls data from another file (left it out) and makes some transformations to certain columns. It works properly.
However, I want to delete columns CL to EF in the worksheet (named destSheet), which is not working. I also want to delete the entire row in instances where the date in column A in the format mm/dd/yyyy is not in the current month of this year. This is also not working.
Sub ProcessReports()
    Dim networkFolder As String: networkFolder = "\\AAAA\bbbb\"
    Dim folder As String
    Dim subfolder As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim destWb As Workbook
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet
    Dim destRow As Long
    Dim folderDate As String
    Dim dateFormat As String: dateFormat = "yyyymmdd"
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim file As String
    Dim dateValue As Variant ' Declare as Variant for For Each loop
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim p As Long
    Dim currentMonth As Integer
    Dim currentYear As Integer
    Dim cellDate As Date
    
    currentMonth = Month(Date)
    currentYear = Year(Date)
    
    ' Open the destination workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set destWb = Workbooks("destination.xlsm")
    If destWb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Destination workbook 'destination.xlsm' is not open.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Set the destination sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set destSheet = destWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If destSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet 'Sheet1' does not exist in the destination workbook.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    destRow = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
    '''Identify all folders
    Dim fldrStack As Object: Set fldrStack = CreateObject("System.Collections.Stack")
    
    folder = Dir(networkFolder, vbDirectory)
    
    While folder <> ""
        If IsDateFormat(folder, dateFormat) Then fldrStack.Push folder
        folder = Dir()
    Wend
    '''
    
    '''Loop through the identified folders
    While fldrStack.Count > 0
        folder = fldrStack.Pop()
        
        folderDate = Format(CDate(Left(folder, 4) & "-" & Mid(folder, 5, 2) & "-" & Right(folder, 2)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        subfolder = networkFolder & folder & "\subname\Reports\"
        file = Dir(subfolder & "Report_" & folder & ".xls")

        If file <> "" Then
            filePath = subfolder & file
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
            Set sourceWs = wb.Sheets(1)

            ' Define the data range
            lastRow = sourceWs.Cells(sourceWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set dataRange = sourceWs.Range("A6:AT" & lastRow)

            ' Apply filters
            dataRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Bob"
            dataRange.AutoFilter Field:=44, Criteria1:="=*Joe*", Operator:=xlAnd

            ' Copy filtered data to destination sheet
            On Error Resume Next
            Set dataRange = sourceWs.Range("A7:AT" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not dataRange Is Nothing Then
                dataRange.Copy destSheet.Cells(destRow, 2) ' Paste starting from column B to leave column A for dates
                
                ' Add the folder date beside each copied row
                For Each cell In destSheet.Range(destSheet.Cells(destRow, 2), destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
                    If cell.Value <> "" Then
                        cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = folderDate
                    End If
                Next cell

                destRow = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End If

            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    Wend
    
    '''Tidy Up
    fldrStack.Clear
    Set fldrStack = Nothing
    
    For j = 1 To 89
         destSheet.Columns(1).Insert Shift:=x1ToRight
    Next j
    
    destSheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        destSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = "Manual"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "C").Value = "BBA"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value = "BA"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "H").Value = 0
        destSheet.Cells(i, "I").Value = "IS"
    Next i
    
    'Deletes columns CL to EF
    destWb.destSheet.Range("CL:EF").EntireColumn.Delete

    'Deletes entries that are not in month to day
    For p = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If IsDate(destSheet.Cells(p, 1).Value) Then
            cellDate = destSheet.Cells(p, 1).Value
            If Month(cellDate) <> currentMonth Or Year(cellDate) <> currentYear Then
                ws.Rows(p).Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next p
            

    
End Sub


Function IsDateFormat(folderName As String, dateFormat As String) As Boolean
    IsDateFormat = (Len(folderName) = Len(dateFormat)) And IsNumeric(Left(folderName, 4)) And IsNumeric(Mid(folderName, 5, 2)) And IsNumeric(Right(folderName, 2))
End Function


"named destSheet" is that the codename ?

destSheet is just the name of the target sheet where the data is being pasted. There shouldn't be issues there since all the data is being copied/pasted and transformed accordingly. The issue is just deleting the unnecessary columns and deleting the old rows

destWb = Workbooks("destination.xlsm")   --> name of the file is destination
destSheet = destWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

destWb.destSheet.Range("CL:EF").Entirecolumn.Delete

Side note: the For i = 1 To lastRow loop can be replaced by the one-liner destSheet.Range("B1:D" & lastRow).Value = Array("0","A+","T").

@MarkS. in testing, the .EntireColumn appears to be redundant.

@BigBen also in testing I saw their code should have worked. So what are we thinking? One of the variables isn't right? My guess is that if this is grabbing info from another sheet something is getting mixed up during the code where we're no longer in the same workbook.

Have you shown all the code ? Where is the line  destSheet = destWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Initially, I left out all the code since it was way too long. I've updated it now.

@MarkS. the delete line that you provided isn't working.

@CDP1802 Yes I included it

destWb.destSheet.Range("CL:EF").EntireColumn.Delete ?? remove the destWB and ws.Rows(p).Delete ?? should that be destSheet not ws ?

@SamSmith if the code isn't working it seems to be related to the variables or something in the process interfering, as Ben and I both tested it, saw it worked, and even tested if you removed .entirecolumn it should still work. Do any of the lines after this work as intended (see in your question it isn't)? The only difference when I did it is I defined it as Thisworkbook and the specific sheet I was on, so I get the impression one of those other components is the cause.

@MarkS. Thanks for the insight. None of the code is executed after the for loop i=1 to Last Row.. That's the last thing that is being executed

@CDP1802 thanks for the catch, I tried those and it doesn't work either

Hint: liberal use of Debug.Print or stepping through with F8 can help you trace code execution.

For i = 1 To lastRow isn't lastRow the last row of a sourceWs, should it be destRow in that loop ?

Shift:=x1ToRight should be Shift:=xlToRight
