How can I get rid of overflow error in VBA?
I have the following VBA code. Essentially, I pull in data from other spreadsheets in my network drive and make some manipulations to the data that I pulled in. The code is executing entirely, and I'm getting the output that I need. However, at the end of each time I run the macro I keep getting an "overflow error" with the only options to "End", "Debug", or "Help". I just want to stop this dialog box error from coming up. What can I do?
Sub ProcessCollateralReports()
    Dim networkFolder As String: networkFolder = "\\pathname\foldername\"
    Dim folder As String
    Dim subfolder As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim destWb As Workbook 'Destination workbook - this is the workbook where we are pasting our values from the source worksheet
    Dim destSheet As Worksheet 'Destination worksheet - this is the sheet within the workbook where we are pasting our values. This is the final worksheet that we need at the end
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sourceWs As Worksheet 'Source worksheet - this is where we are extracting the values from
    Dim destRow As Long
    Dim folderDate As String
    Dim dateFormat As String: dateFormat = "yyyymmdd"
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim file As String
    Dim dateValue As Variant ' Declare as Variant for For Each loop
    Dim r As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    
    ' Open the destination workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set destWb = Workbooks("endfile.xlsm")
    If destWb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Destination workbook 'endfile.xlsm' is not open.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' Set the destination sheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set destSheet = destWb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    If destSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet 'Sheet1' does not exist in the destination workbook.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    destRow = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
    '''Identify all folders
    Dim fldrStack As Object: Set fldrStack = CreateObject("System.Collections.Stack")
    
    folder = Dir(networkFolder, vbDirectory)
    
    While folder <> ""
        If IsDateFormat(folder, dateFormat) Then fldrStack.Push folder
        folder = Dir()
    Wend
    '''
    
    '''Loop through the identified folders
    While fldrStack.Count > 0
        folder = fldrStack.Pop()
        
        folderDate = Format(CDate(Left(folder, 4) & "-" & Mid(folder, 5, 2) & "-" & Right(folder, 2)), "mm/dd/yyyy")
        subfolder = networkFolder & folder & "\Internal\Internal_Reports\"
        file = Dir(subfolder & "Position_Summary_Report_" & folder & ".xls")

        If file <> "" Then
            filePath = subfolder & file
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
            Set sourceWs = wb.Sheets(1)

            ' Define the data range
            lastRow = sourceWs.Cells(sourceWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            Set dataRange = sourceWs.Range("A6:AT" & lastRow)

            ' Apply filters
            dataRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Bob"
            dataRange.AutoFilter Field:=44, Criteria1:="=*Alice*", Operator:=xlAnd

            ' Copy filtered data to destination sheet
            On Error Resume Next
            Set dataRange = sourceWs.Range("A7:AT" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not dataRange Is Nothing Then
                dataRange.Copy destSheet.Cells(destRow, 2) ' Paste starting from column B to leave column A for dates
                
                ' Add the folder date beside each copied row
                For Each cell In destSheet.Range(destSheet.Cells(destRow, 2), destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
                    If cell.Value <> "" Then
                        cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = folderDate
                    End If
                Next cell

                destRow = destSheet.Cells(destSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End If

            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    Wend
    
    '''Tidy Up
    fldrStack.Clear
    Set fldrStack = Nothing
    
    '''Adding new columns to insert the transformed and pasted data
    For j = 1 To 89
         destSheet.Columns(1).Insert Shift:=x1ToRight
    Next j
    
    '''Deleting the first row since it is blank in the output
    destSheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    
    '''Various transformations
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        destSheet.Cells(i, "B").Value = "Manual"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "C").Value = "BBNA"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "D").Value = "BBNA"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "H").Value = 0
        destSheet.Cells(i, "I").Value = "IS"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "L").Value = "Bob"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "M").Value = "NOTE"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "N").Value = "Alice"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "R").Value = "Bob"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "W").Value = 1.01
        destSheet.Cells(i, "U").Value = "Jane"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "AM").Value = "B"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "AN").Value = "Rob"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "AP").Value = 0
        destSheet.Cells(i, "AR").Value = "2049"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "AT").Value = "T"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "AU").Value = 360
        destSheet.Cells(i, "AX").Value = 0
        destSheet.Cells(i, "AY").Value = 0
        destSheet.Cells(i, "BB").Value = 0
        destSheet.Cells(i, "BC").Value = 0
        destSheet.Cells(i, "BE").Value = "Smith"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "BF").Value = "Steve"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "BG").Value = "BBNA"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "CD").Value = "MATT"
        destSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value = destSheet.Cells(i, "CL").Value
        destSheet.Cells(i, "J").Value = destSheet.Cells(i, "DK").Value
        destSheet.Cells(i, "K").Value = destSheet.Cells(i, "DJ").Value
        
        '''More transformations and formatting
        Select Case destSheet.Cells(i, "CN").Value
            Case "abc"
                destSheet.Cells(i, "E").Value = "BBNA - abc"
                destSheet.Cells(i, "F").Value = "1234"
                destSheet.Cells(i, "G").Value = "Jane Doe"
            Case "def"
                destSheet.Cells(i, "E").Value = "BBNA - def"
                destSheet.Cells(i, "F").Value = "5678"
                destSheet.Cells(i, "G").Value = "Rob Smith"
        End Select
        If IsDate(destSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value) Then
             destSheet.Cells(i, "AQ").Value = Format(destSheet.Cells(i, "A").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        End If
        If IsDate(destSheet.Cells(i, "DI").Value) Then
             destSheet.Cells(i, "BN").Value = Format(destSheet.Cells(i, "DI").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        End If
        destSheet.Cells(i, "BZ").Value = destSheet.Cells(i, "AQ").Value
        destSheet.Cells(i, "BA").Value = destSheet.Cells(i, "AO").Value * destSheet.Cells(i, "BK").Value
        destSheet.Cells(i, "BD").Value = destSheet.Cells(i, "AZ").Value * destSheet.Cells(i, "BK").Value
    Next i
     
End Sub

'''Getting the date in the right format
Function IsDateFormat(folderName As String, dateFormat As String) As Boolean
    IsDateFormat = (Len(folderName) = Len(dateFormat)) And IsNumeric(Left(folderName, 4)) And IsNumeric(Mid(folderName, 5, 2)) And IsNumeric(Right(folderName, 2))
End Function


If you click Debug which line is highlighted?

A few side notes: Why not initially use destRow = 1 so you don't have to delete the 1st row? Isn't inserting 89 columns one by one time-consuming? You could probably use destSheet.Columns("A").Resize(, 89).Insert instead. You're using lastRow = sourceWs.Cells(sourceWs.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row for all source sheets and then you're using For i = 1 To lastRow in your destination sheet. That's not going to work correctly. Instead of lastRow, use destRow - 1 if you haven't deleted the first row.

Shift:=x1ToRight should be Shift:=xlToRight ie xl (letter L) not x1 (number one). This was pointed out on your post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78619232/
